# Clojure, concat multiple sequences into one

Tags: clojure

The following line: `(repeat 4 [2 3])`

gives me this: `([2 3] [2 3] [2 3] [2 3])`

How do I create one vector or list from the above list of vectors so that I get this?: `[2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3]`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [(flatten x)](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/1.2.0/clojure.core/flatten)
>   Takes any nested combination of sequential things (lists,
>   vectors, etc.) and returns their contents as a single, flat sequence.
>   (flatten nil) returns nil.

```
(flatten (repeat 4 [2 3]))  ;(2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3)
```

Comment: The problem with flatten is it is often too aggressive, it stops being useful as soon as you want any subsequence anywhere in the sequence to remain. Often using flatten is a sign that you should be generating your data differently (ie. mapcat instead of map, cons instead of list).

Comment: https://chouser.us/apply-concat/ explains why using flatten is wrong most of the time - namely it is recursive and flattens also nested structures (if you have a vector of vectors of vectors) - are you sure you want that? Due to its use of `sequential?` it skips sets and arrays. And it is more complicated and I'd think performance-expensive.

Answer (score 20):

`concat` is in fact exactly the function you want

```
user> (apply concat (repeat 4 [2 3]))
(2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3)
```

this even works with lazy input:

```
user> (take 8 (apply concat (repeat [2 3])))
(2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3)
```

This is an alternative:

```
user> (def flatten-1 (partial mapcat identity))
#'user/flatten-1
user> (flatten-1 (repeat 4 [2 3]))
(2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3)
```

it is compatible with laziness and unlike flatten preserves any substructure (only doing one level of flattening)

```
user> (take 12 (flatten-1 (repeat [2 3 [4]])))
(2 3 [4] 2 3 [4] 2 3 [4] 2 3 [4])
```

Comment: There is a great exploration of alternatives in https://chouser.us/apply-concat/, which concludes that `apply concat` is the way to go. If you want to get a vector out and forego laziness then `(sequence cat xs)` or `(eduction cat xs)` are the way to go (see the article for details).

Answer (score 6):

```
(take 8 (cycle [2 3]))
;; => (2 3 2 3 2 3 2 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

Pedantically speaking, you asked for a vector, so:

```
(->> [2 3] cycle (take 8) vec)
```

I feel cycle is a little more appropriate than concat (though it uses concat itself) as it indicates "cycle through the elements of this sequence" rather than "concatenate the following sequences together". Just my two cents, matter of opinion.